# Is my printer a network printer?

Tags: delphi, printing

On my PC (1) I have a Brother DCP printer. It's a network-printer.
I'm running Delphi 7 Enterprise on XP (sp3).

Now I want Delphi to tell me It is a Network printer.

I have this code :

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
   Coinitialize(NIL); 
   DOLPT2(); 
   // ShowMessage('test6 '); 
   COUninitialize; 
end;

Procedure Tform1.DOLPT2();
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2','','');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where Default = True','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
     begin
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('Name    %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_NETWORK  %s',[Integer(FWbemObject.PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_NETWORK)]));// Integer
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL    %s',[Integer(FWbemObject.PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL)]));// Integer
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
        FWbemObject := Unassigned;
     end
  ELSE
     BEGIN
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('Name    %s',['Ingen printer']));   // String
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
     END;
end;
```

(* Code copied from RUI - Thanks to him *)

I get an error message saying "METHOD  SELECTED ATTRIBUTE NOT SUPPORTED BY AUTOMATION OBJECT " on both attributes .

NAME-attribute works fine.

I have tried '  wnetenumresource  ' too, but that does not work properly - it seems.

What can I do to find the NETWORK-printer ?

Comment: query for local=false, this will give you all network printers

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  Sorry - but I don't know what you mean. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Change your WMI query to `SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where Local = False`

Comment: @whosrdaddy:: Just tried it.   Result  : Name-attribute says:   NO PRINTER !    (Danish:  ' Ingen printer ' )   thereby skipping reading the other attributes ...

Comment: @whosrdaddy - I don't know - this is a genuine question, but does this not just list printers on the local device, i.e. those that would be shown printers page (XP). If this is so, it may be that this printer is not added to the local machine.

Comment: @Dsm, the query will return only network printers that are registered to the computer, not **all** network printers. Now it may be possible that this query does not work under WinXP, when I test the query under powershell (win10), it returns all my attached network printers...

Comment: Powershell test: `$query="SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where Local = False"`
`Get-WmiObject -Query $query`

Comment: @whosrdaddy. That is what I thought. I just thought the problem might be that the questioner thought it would return all network machines, not just those registered locally, and that his problem might be an illusion.

Comment: Equally, reading between the lines, it may be that the printer is physically connected to the machine the program is run on, in which case it is a local printer, even if it is shared. Maybe he needs to know that it is shared, rather than remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure specifically what you are looking for, but this gives all the likely types. Note that I have removed the 'default' restriction - this will only ever return one printer.

```
Procedure Tform2.DOLPT2;
var
  iValue : Cardinal;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2','','');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
     begin
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('Name    %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
        if FWbemObject.Shared then Listbox1.Items.Add( 'Shared' );
        if FWbemObject.Network then Listbox1.Items.Add( 'Networked' );
        if FWbemObject.Local then Listbox1.Items.Add( 'Local' );
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
        FWbemObject := Unassigned;
     end
  ELSE
     BEGIN
        Listbox1.Items.Add(Format('Name    %s',['Ingen printer']));   // String
        Listbox1.Items.Add(' ');
     END;
end;
```

If you want to know what other fields are available, Google Win32_Printer class and go to the Microsoft site.

Comment: Copied your code snippet, modified it a little (change IF to IF THEN ELSE to check if attibuted was implemented (remembering PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_NETWORK). My network topography is: 4 (nearly) eaual PC (ThinkCentre Lenovo/IBM) interconnected to a 5 PORT Hub/Router and the printer is connected to the Hub/Router.     ALL MACHINES give same answer - ;  name = Brother..., LOCAL = TRUE, all other attributes = FALSE.....  Why the NETWORK and SHARED attribute reports FALSE I don't know, but I guess (faulty ?) it's because it's a WORKGROUP (remembering your first paragraph earlier.)  NO SERVER at all.

Comment: @KristianSander Thanks for the clarification. It makes your problem much clearer. I would have expected Networked to be TRUE and Local to be FALSE. I would also have expected Shared to be FALSE (which it is). Perhaps whosrdaddy is right and the database does not work properly for XP, but more likely it is your Printer/Driver. I am guessing you have to use a special install procedure for this printer, and I guess that printer driver registers itself as a local printer even though the printer itself is remote. But these are all guesses.

Comment: Maybe try adding another printer locally to one of the machines and sharing it with the others to see if that behaves as expected.

Comment: YES, you're right. Then printer requires an installable driver (CD) on each machine and I guess (too) that sets the attrib's. to FALSE . Anyway all the machines "know" their printer, so if it is a LOCAL - or NETWORK- printer is not that important.  Everything works fine, so now it's merely an academical question. Later I wil add another printer to the network and check each attribute again.  ANYWAY:  THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP . Sorry for asking (I'm a newbie here), but how do I give you credit ?

Comment: @KristianSander You click the accepted button to the left of the answer. You may also upvote.

Comment: A network printer is local to the computer that connects to it if the computer uses a local TCP/IP port.

Comment: *" .. A local printer is any printer that is not connected to a shared network printer.  This includes [...], TCP/IP printers, [...]."* - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn581925(v%3Dws.11)#only-if-local-printer-is-not-present-5

Answer (score -1):

Your question... Is my printer a network printer?
Its easy to find out. Check if your printer model number have letter N at final.
For ex. N=network, DN duplex and network.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this piece of code from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993576/how-can-i-find-if-there-are-printers-installed-using-delphi) can help you. The `idx_Net_printer` is a constant that defines if the printer is a network printer. Of couse you will need to adapt the code. I have not tested it.

```
procedure TMyForm.RefreshPrinterList;
var
  I: Integer;
  NewItem: TComboExItem;
  PPrinterEnumArray, PLocator: PPrinterInfo2;
  ArraySize, BufferSize: cardinal;
  strBuffer: string;
const
  idx_Default_Net_printer = 0;
  idx_Net_printer = 1;
  idx_Default_Local_printer = 2;
  idx_Local_printer = 3;

begin
  DefaultPrinterName := getDefaultPrinterName;
  cbPrinterList.ItemsEx.Clear;
  // S.G. 4/4/2008: list all other printers
  // S.G. 4/4/2008: Get the necessary buffer size
  ArraySize := 0;
  BufferSize := 0;
  PPrinterEnumArray := nil;
  EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL or PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, nil, 2, nil, 0, BufferSize, ArraySize);
  PPrinterEnumArray := AllocMem(BufferSize);
  try
    if EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL or PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, nil, 2, PPrinterEnumArray, BufferSize, BufferSize, ArraySize) then
    begin
      PLocator := PPrinterEnumArray;
      if ArraySize > 0 then
      begin
        for I := 0 to ArraySize - 1 do    // Iterate
        begin
          NewItem := cbPrinterList.ItemsEx.Add;
          strBuffer := StrPas(PLocator^.pPrinterName);
          UniqueString(strBuffer); // make sure we have a unique string instance and not a pointer
          NewItem.Caption := strBuffer;

          if AnsiSameText(DefaultPrinterName, strBuffer) then
          begin
            // default printer
            if  (PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL AND PLocator^.Attributes) <> 0 then
            begin
              // Local, default printer
              NewItem.ImageIndex := idx_Default_Local_printer;
            end
            else
            begin
              // Network default printer
              NewItem.ImageIndex := idx_Default_Net_printer;
            end;
            cbPrinterList.ItemIndex := NewItem.Index;
          end
          else
          begin
            // default printer
            if  (PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL AND PLocator^.Attributes) <> 0 then
            begin
              // Local, default printer
              NewItem.ImageIndex := idx_Local_printer;
            end
            else
            begin
              // Network default printer
              NewItem.ImageIndex := idx_Net_printer;
            end;
          end;
          Inc(PLocator);
        end;    // for
      end;
    end;
  finally // wrap up
    FreeMem(PPrinterEnumArray);
  end;    // try/finally
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code-snippet. Unfortunately It wouldn't run properly. .